# ECMA-262 7.0 GetValue(V)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can anyone explain to me with examples how this algorithm works?

```
GetValue (V)#

1. ReturnIfAbrupt(V).
2. If Type(V) is not Reference, return V. 
3. Let base be GetBase(V). 
4. If IsUnresolvableReference(V) is true, throw a ReferenceError exception. 
5. If IsPropertyReference(V) is true, then  
    a. If HasPrimitiveBase(V) is true, then  
        i. Assert: In this case, base will never be null or undefined.  
        ii. Let base be ToObject(base).  
    b. Return ? base.[[Get]](GetReferencedName(V), GetThisValue(V)). 
6. Else base must be an Environment Record,  
    a. Return ? base.GetBindingValue(GetReferencedName(V), IsStrictReference(V)) (see 8.1.1).
```

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-getvalue

It would be nice if someone with examples explained how it works. I tried, but I did not understand much.

Examples for explanation:

```
let a = 10, b = {name: "Unknown"};
(null, a);
(null, a.name);
(null, b);
(null, b.name);
(null, b.surname);
(null, 10);
/// etc...
```

Comment: this looks like pseudo code, do you have to implement this? Provide what you did...

Comment: @Hitmands So that you understand me, I want to understand on a real examples how it works. For example, we'll take the addition `("" + Object.prototype)`. For addition, there is also an algorithm and it calls GetValue(V) for each operand and I would like to consider all branches of possible cases in the algorithm (GetValue()).

Comment: What do you mean, "how this works"? That's just what an algorithm *is*, a description of how something works. What did you try but could not understand?

Comment: @Bergi, methinks, author want sample, how apply this algorithm to concrete code, like code in block _Examples for explanation_. For example what branches would be selected if write just variable name, or variable property etc.

Comment: @Grundy He should show some effort and post what he thinks how the algorithm executes on those examples, then. Or ask more specifically about some part of that process where he tried and failed.

Comment: @Bergi "how this works" - I mean when every branch will be reached. That is, there is a piece of code `(null, a)`. How will the above algorithm work? On the points, why this or that branch will work. It is better if you write all possible code options for this algorithm. So it will be easier to understand what is happening in it on examples.

Comment: @MaximPro The first thing to understand might be that `GetValue` is not an algorithm that is applied to pieces of code at all. It's a helper used by algorithms that evaluate expressions - in the example `(null, a)` [the comma operator evaluation uses `GetValue` twice](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-comma-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation). So what do you want to know there?

Comment: @Bergi I have problem on every case. I can not show when i failed.
As far as I know, the comma operator `return` a pure result from `GetValue(a)`

Comment: @MaximPro If you just want to know where references with the properties that make it take another branch can occur, you should look through the spec at every occasion where a `Reference` is constructed. I think your question is far too broad.

Comment: @Bergi what do you think about answer skyline3000

Comment: @MaximPro His explanation of the algorithm is mostly accurate, but doesn't introduce new information (to me, at least - and as he says, all this can be found in the spec) - or was there something particular that you did not understand here? His examples sections looks very much confused.

Comment: @Bergi ok. What do you think about his examples? Are they correct?

Answer (score 1):

This segment gives more context:

> ...The Reference Specification Type#
>
> NOTE The Reference type is used to explain the behaviour of such
>   operators as delete, typeof, the assignment operators, the super
>   keyword and other language features. For example, the left-hand
>   operand of an assignment is expected to produce a reference.
>
> A Reference is a resolved name or property binding. A Reference
>   consists of three components, the base value, the referenced name and
>   the Boolean valued strict reference flag. The base value is either
>   undefined, an Object, a Boolean, a String, a Symbol, a Number, or an
>   Environment Record. A base value of undefined indicates that the
>   Reference could not be resolved to a binding. The referenced name is a
>   String or Symbol value.
>
> A Super Reference is a Reference that is used to represents a name
>   binding that was expressed using the super keyword. A Super Reference
>   has an additional thisValue component and its base value will never be
>   an Environment Record.
>
> The following abstract operations are used in this specification to
>   access the components of references:
>
> - GetBase(V). Returns the base value component of the reference V.
> - GetReferencedName(V). Returns the referenced name component of the
>     reference V.
> - IsStrictReference(V). Returns the strict reference flag
>     component of the reference V.
> - HasPrimitiveBase(V). Returns true if Type(base) is Boolean, String, Symbol, or Number.
> - IsPropertyReference(V). Returns true if either the base value is an
>     object or HasPrimitiveBase(V) is true; otherwise returns false.
> - IsUnresolvableReference(V). Returns true if the base value is
>     undefined and false otherwise.
> - IsSuperReference(V). Returns true if
>     this reference has a thisValue component. The following abstract
>     operations are used in this specification to operate on references...

This is language internals. From a quick glance it looks like it is related to type inference before additional actions are performed on the value. This kind of operations are performed on a lower level when you call things like

```
delete someObject.prop
```

or

```
typeof someVarIdentifier
```

Example:

```
("" + a);
```

Parse expression -> getValue("") + getValue(a) -> string{""} + (number{10} -> cast to string) -> concat("","10") -> "10"

Comment: I've read about the reference type, but it also does not give a complete understanding of when we go through GetValue

Your example of execution of a chain of algorithms (binary +, ToString, ToPrimitive). I do not need their explanation, I'm only interested in the GetValue algorithm

Comment: I'm interested in various situations that occur in GetValue. I'm interested in what cases it is possible to achieve this or that branch (There are no examples of their achievement in the algorithm, so it is difficult to understand when this is achievable)

Comment: If you can release, you can use more light variant. For example `(null, a)`. Where in this expression return last expression after comma. It will return GetValue(a) clearly.

Comment: I am sorry mate, I can't help you further with this topic. Probably only the guys at TC39 can give good explanation.

Comment: It's developers of ECMAScript?

Comment: With a bit of delay - yes :)